# To get data from the list in Required JSON format

Tags: c#, json

Below is my code which gives the JSON DATA,

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            List<HMData> Data_Content = new List<HMData>();
            for (int l = 0; l < 7; l++)
            {

                Value_LfromList = LValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
                Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
                Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
                Data_Content.Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
            }
            data_list.Add(Data_Content);
        } 
var data = new{data=data_list};
var series = new []{ data};
var obj = new { chart, series };
string result = jSearializer.Serialize(obj);
```

output I am getting is as follows,

```
{
  "chart":{"type":"bubble"},
  "series":
   [
     {"data":
       [
          [
            {"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":9,"z":63},
            {"x":5,"y":9,"z":45},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},{"x":2,"y":6,"z":12},
            {"x":3,"y":5,"z":15}
          ],
          [
            {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
            {"x":9,"y":6,"z":54},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":8,"z":24},
            {"x":4,"y":3,"z":12}
          ],
          [
            {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
            {"x":8,"y":7,"z":56},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},
            {"x":5,"y":8,"z":40}
          ],
          [
            {"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},
            {"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":8,"y":6,"z":48},{"x":7,"y":3,"z":21},
            {"x":6,"y":7,"z":42}
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I want data to be as follows,

```
{
"chart":{"type":"bubble"},
"series":
    [
    {"data":[{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":9,"z":63},{"x":5,"y":9,"z":45},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},{"x":2,"y":6,"z":12},{"x":3,"y":5,"z":15}]},
    {"data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":9,"y":6,"z":54},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":8,"z":24},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12}]},
    {"data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":8,"y":7,"z":56},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":8,"z":40}]},
    {"data":[{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":8,"y":6,"z":48},{"x":7,"y":3,"z":21},{"x":6,"y":7,"z":42}]}
    ]
}
```

In short,my 4 data object get store in one data string ,I want to have different data string ...Any idea how I can do this,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<object> dataList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<object>();
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            List<HMData> Data_Content = new List<HMData>();
            for (int l = 0; l < 7; l++)
            {

                Value_LfromList = LValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
                Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
                Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
                Data_Content.Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
            }
            dataList.Add(new {data = Data_Content});
        } 
var series = dataList;
var obj = new { chart, series };
string result = jSearializer.Serialize(obj);
```

The problem in your solutions lies in the fact that in order to get te result you want, you need to associate "data" to each Data_Content (from each inner iteration).

Therefore, changing it this way, in **dataList** you will get the equivalent of this:

```
[
{"data":[{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":9,"z":63},{"x":5,"y":9,"z":45},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},{"x":2,"y":6,"z":12},{"x":3,"y":5,"z":15}]},
{"data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":9,"y":6,"z":54},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":8,"z":24},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12}]},
{"data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":8,"y":7,"z":56},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":8,"z":40}]},
{"data":[{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":8,"y":6,"z":48},{"x":7,"y":3,"z":21},{"x":6,"y":7,"z":42}]}
]
```

Then we assign this to **series** so as to get that key for the whole list, and then add your **chart** and **series** objects to the final **obj** which you then serialize.

Hope this helps.
Cheers.